# finding max value from input in java

Tags: java

I am working on a school lab. The program does execute to an extent. It is finding the max value given user input.I would appreciate what I have to do so I can fix it.

Instructions: Write a method, `findMax()`, that repeatedly reads in integers until a negative integer is read and keeps track of the largest integer that has been read. `findMax()` then returns the largest number entered.

When zybooks enters the inputs:

```
2 77 17 4 -1  it returns   77
1 3 99 23 4 -3  it returns  99
45 -1     error 
55 45 35 25 15 5 0 -5    it returns 55
0 10 20 30 40 -50   returns 20 
0 -100    returns  error
```

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
    
public class Max {
       
    public int findMax() {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        int maxSoFar = 0;
        int currValue;
        int numValues = 5;
        int i;
    
        numValues ;
    
        for (i = 0; i < numValues; ++i) {
            currValue = scnr.nextInt();
    
            if (i == 0) { // First iteration
                maxSoFar = currValue;
            } else if (currValue > maxSoFar) {
                maxSoFar = currValue;
            }
        }
    
        if (numValues > 0) {
            maxSoFar = maxSoFar;
        }
          
        return maxSoFar;  
    }
       
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Max test = new Max();
        System.out.println(test.findMax());
    }
}
```

Comment: `45 -1 error` why should it return error? is it expected output or your actual output?

Comment: 20 0 -100 returns error .why should it return error? Like as the text of your question it should return 20 as answer!!

Comment: Why `0 10 20 30 40 -50   returns 20`?  It should be 40.

Comment: whats is this `numValues ;`?

Comment: It probably returns errors, because there are only 2 numbers, but the code tries to read 5?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to specify how many times the loop has to execute - to be exact, you shouldn't as the instructions ask you to read integers till a negative integer is read. You can just use `do { ... } while (..);` and have it run as many times as needed.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Max {
   
   public int findMax() {
   
   Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      int maxSoFar = 0;
      int currValue;

      do {
         currValue = scnr.nextInt();

         if (currValue > maxSoFar) {
            maxSoFar = currValue;
         }
      } while (currValue >= 0);
      
      return maxSoFar;
      
   }
   
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Max test = new Max();
      System.out.println(test.findMax());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. You've to add 2 things.

- Take input until user gives negative number
- Output `error` when there's only one input (although, you didn't mention the error case clearly, I'm assuming this from the input)

Take input until user gives negative number:

In your code you're taking input `numValues` time. Which you initialized with `5`.

So basically you're taking `5` inputs.

To take input until you're given a negative number, you can do like below:

```
while(1)
{
    currValue = scnr.nextInt();
    if(currValue < 0) break;
    else
    {
        // do the rest of the task
    }
}
```

Output error when there's only one input:

You can keep a `counter` of how many valid inputs you've taken so far.
If `count <= 1`, then you'll show `error` as output.

Overall code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Max
{
    public int findMax()
    {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        int maxSoFar = 0;
        int currValue;
        int validInputCounter = 0;

        while(1)
        {
            currValue = scnr.nextInt();
            if(currValue < 0) break;
            else
            {
                validInputCounter++;

                if (validInputCounter == 1)   // First iteration
                {
                    maxSoFar = currValue;
                }
                else if (currValue > maxSoFar)
                {
                    maxSoFar = currValue;
                }
            }
        }

        if (validInputCounter <= 1)
        {
            return -1;
        }

        return maxSoFar;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Max test = new Max();

        int maxValue = test.findMax();

        if(maxValue == -1) System.out.println("Error");
        else System.out.println(maxValue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to compare `currValue` and `maxSoFar`. Like this,

```
public class Max {

    public int findMax() {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        int maxSoFar = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int numValues = 5;

        for (int i = 0; i < numValues; ++i) {
            int currValue = scnr.nextInt();

            if (currValue > maxSoFar) {
                maxSoFar = currValue;
            }
        }

        return maxSoFar;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Max test = new Max();
        System.out.println(test.findMax());
    }
}
```